# Openlayers IE security issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, openlayers

I'm working on a project that is using the OpenLayers ordinance survey for mapping and have been running into a very awkward issue. The issue only seems to live in Internet Explorer. The problem is as follows;
When loading the map, OpenLayers creates a dynamic .js file and inside this file there is a line of code that does the following :

```
setImgSrc:function(a){var b=this.imgDiv;b.style.visibility="hidden";b.style.opacity=0;a&&(this.crossOriginKeyword&&("data:"!==a.substr(0,5)?b.setAttribute("crossorigin",
this.crossOriginKeyword):b.removeAttribute("crossorigin")),b.src=a)}
```

The problem resides on the b.src=a line, everytime I run in IE ONLY I get a0x800c000e - JavaScript runtime error: A security problem occurred.

I've done research so far and having been turning up many leads, most of what I see is hosting images on your own server, but the resources are not available to accomplish this. If anyone can shed any kind of light on this issue it will be greatly appreciated.

Using Openlayers Version 2.12

Answer (score 0):

Uh, provide some examples of 'a'?

Also, go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms775145(v=vs.85).aspx , find INET_E_SECURITY_PROBLEM, and see if the errors codes shown look relevent. Eg. could it be a certificate error?